# Why are't Object related methods inside the Object prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, prototype

There are methods like `Object.values` fo `Object.keys`, but why aren't these methods inside the object's prototype? Is there a good reason for this?

Example:

```
const user = { name: 'John', role: 'admin' };
const keys = user.keys() // instead of Object.keys(user);
const values = user.values() // instead of Object.values(user);
```

Comment: Because that would conflict with `const user = {keys: function(){}}; user.keys()`.

Comment: IMO, to keep the `prototype` object as clean as possible as not every object is going to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Because *everything is an object in JavaScript*. If you add a method to the Object's prototype, it would be inherited to *everything*, it can't (or shouldn't, as it then hides the original method) be used as a name of a custom method. That means that if the `Object.prototype` would get polluted  with a lot of methods, it would make the choice of property names more difficult:

```
  1..keys() // Did you expect this to work?
```